# Python Spam Email Sending Errors

Tags: python, gmail

```
import smtplib
fromaddr = "Insert your email here"
toaddr = ["insert receivers adress here"]


message = """From: fromname  <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: Insert Subject here"""

emails_done = 1 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "InsertPassword")
for i in range(int(raw_input('how many emails?'))):
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr,message)
    print(emails_done)
    emails_done = emails_done + 1
server.quit()
```

Im trying to spam my friend with 100 emails as a prank, but i have a few problems with the code, i get alot of different errors such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Data/Users/106299/Desktop/EMAIL .py", line 45, in <module>
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr,message)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 723, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 462, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 387, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 360, in getreply
    + str(e))
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Ive Gotten up to 78 emails and it always ends there. Also sometimes it sends in one big email thread/change, rather then 100 separate emails.Here is another

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Data/Users/106299/Desktop/EMAIL .py", line 45, in <module>
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr,message)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 723, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 462, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 387, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 363, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I am running python 2.7.8 on a MacBook Air
Any help would be appreciated :>
P.S sorry for crap formatting, first post.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that gmail is rejecting requests after a certain number per second.
Try putting `server.set_debuglevel(1)` right after `server.starttls()`, this will let you see the debug details of the function call. This information will likely lead you to the solution.